# yield versus duration in cash-and-carry (basis) trade

Tags: cross-currency-basis, basis

I am trying to run a cash-and-carry (basis) trade.  I'm having trouble understanding how to weigh the tradeoffs between yield, annualized yield and duration/time to expiry.

Suppose we are in a contango situation so I am looking to buy spot and short the futures of this asset.  There is a contract expiring in 3 months and one expiring in 6 months.  The 3 months contract has a higher annualized yield but obviously expires sooner.  The volatility is high so there is a chance that both contracts could go into backwardation prior to expiry and which point I would exit the position to realize the gains earlier.

I'm not sure how to approach the math on how to determine which position has a better return profile.  Higher annualized yield for shorter period or larger absolute basis?   Can anyone give me any pointers as to how to look at this optimization problem?

Thanks alot!

Comment: To compare basis at two different maturities I find it helpful to look at the "basis per day" i.e. (F-S)/(365*T) for the two contracts. (Assuming equal risks I would prefer to invest in the strategy with the higher BPD).

Comment: Thanks for your help @noob2 - does this BPD give you a different comparison than comparing the annualized yields of the two maturities?  Also, I'm not sure I follow the denominator here - do I need the 365 there or can I just divide by the days remaining in the contract?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question about the yields. Yes, in the denominator of BPD I just use the actual number of days.